# How to perform changes live on UIView in Storyboard without setting any @IBinspectable property?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7-beta6

In Storyboard I have `UITextField`, I also created custom class:

```
class WLTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        layer.cornerRadius = 2
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}
```

Then attached this class to my `UITextField`:

[image]

But, there is no result for this in Storyboard. How can I achieve this? I need to get such effect like it is with `@IBDesignables`. But since I know what I need to set up for every text field, I do not need set a value and then update this within `didSet`.

**Do I need to set at least one value to make changes live in Storyboard on some UIView?**

Comment: If you don't flag yoru class as @IBDesignable then you will only see a generic view in interface builder.

Comment: I marked my class with `@IBDesignable` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a component to render in the Interface Builder you must flag the class as `@IBDesignable` and you must implement the initialise `init(frame: CGRect)` -

```
@IBDesignable class WLTextField: UITextField {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupLayer()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayer()
    }

    func setupLayer () {
        layer.cornerRadius = 2
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}
```